# How to get key name of a object and update the corresponding key's State in React

Tags: reactjs

I am facing issue to set state `onChange`.

The following `handleChangeInputMobile` gives only the current value, not the current target.

For mobile number field validation I am trying to use `PhoneInput` from `react-phone-number-input`.

But I am facing issue to update the state `onChange`.

```js
class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      mobile: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirm_password: ""
    },
    errors: {},
    disabled: true
  };

  handleChangeInputMobile({ currentTarget: input }) {
    // I am not able to get current target here. It gives only value

    const data = { ...this.state.data };

    data[input.name] = input.value;
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    const { mobile } = this.state.data;
    <Mobile
      handleChangeInputMobile={this.handleChangeInputMobile}
      mobile={mobile}
    />;
  }
}
export default Form;

import PhoneInput from "react-phone-number-input";

class Mobile extends Component {
  render() {
    const { handleChangeInputMobile } = this.props;
    const { mobile } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <PhoneInput
          country="IN"
          id="mobile"
          name="mobile"
          value={mobile}
          onChange={handleChangeInputMobile}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Mobile;
```

Comment: You should also not mutate the state with data[input.name] = input.value.Wwrite it like this: this.setState(prevState => ({data: {...prevState.data, [input.name]: input.value}}))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input),

`onChange` prop of `PhoneInput` from `react-phone-number-input` directly works with `value`, you need to explicitly send `name`.

```
onChange={mobile => handleChangeInputMobile(mobile,"mobile")}
```

And your `handleChangeInputMobile` function should be,

```
handleChangeInputMobile(value,key) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({data: {...prevState.data, [key]: value}}), ()=> console.log(this.state)) 
}
```

**Note:** You are directly mutating the `state`, you should use `prevState` and update your state as shown above.

Also in your `Form` component you forgot to `return`, might be a typo.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-85ubrr)

Answer (score 3):

Trying changing `input.value` to `e.target.value` like so:

```
handleChangeInputMobile = (e) => {

 this.setState({
    [e.target.id]: e.target.value
  })

}
```

Comment: @ConAra I've updating my answer. Please try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access to the value with `react-phone-number-input` so you will have to pass your key as a param.

```
handleChangeInputMobile = (value, key) => {
 this.setState({ [key]: value });
}

<PhoneInput
  country="IN"
  id="mobile"
  name="mobile"
  value={mobile}
  onChange={value => handleChangeInputMobile(value, 'mobile')}
/>
```